# Android Unit Test cases for RecyclerView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, junit, android-espresso

I'm trying to write test for the recyclerview in fragment but always seems to be stucks with same error (`androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingRootException`) no matter which solution I try.

Error

```
androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingRootException: Matcher 'with decor view is <DecorView@814c399[]>' did not match any of the following roots: [Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@5c6165e, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@5c6165e, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string={(0,0)(fillxfill) sim={adjust=pan} ty=BASE_APPLICATION wanim=0x10302fe
  fl=LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR SPLIT_TOUCH HARDWARE_ACCELERATED DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS
  pfl=FORCE_DRAW_STATUS_BAR_BACKGROUND}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=2280, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params={(0,0)(fillxfill) sim={adjust=pan} ty=BASE_APPLICATION wanim=0x10302fe
  fl=LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR SPLIT_TOUCH HARDWARE_ACCELERATED DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS
  pfl=FORCE_DRAW_STATUS_BAR_BACKGROUND}, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}}]
```

ListTestFragment.java

```
public class ListTestFragment {
    private ListTestFragment fragment;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<BottomNavigationActivity> activityActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<BottomNavigationActivity>(BottomNavigationActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        activityActivityTestRule.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        activityActivityTestRule.getActivity().openChatFragment(null);
        fragment = activityActivityTestRule.getActivity().chatFragment;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void testClassSetup() {
        System.out.println("Getting test class ready");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void testClassCleanup() {
        System.out.println("Done with tests");
    }

    @After
    public void cleanup() {
        System.out.println("Done with unit test!");
    }


    @Test
    public void testSampleRecyclerVisible() {
        Espresso.onView((withId(R.id.container)))
                .inRoot(RootMatchers.withDecorView(
                        Matchers.is(activityActivityTestRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCaseForRecyclerClick() {
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.recyclerview))
                .inRoot(RootMatchers.withDecorView(
                        Matchers.is(activityActivityTestRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCaseForRecyclerScroll() {
        // Get total item of RecyclerView
        RecyclerView recyclerView = activityActivityTestRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        int itemCount = 20;

        // Scroll to end of page with position
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.recyclerview))
                .inRoot(RootMatchers.withDecorView(
                        Matchers.is(activityActivityTestRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(itemCount - 1));
    }
}
```

openChatFragment() method

```
public void openChatFragment(CloseDialogFragmentInterface closeDialogFragmentInterface) {
        chatFragment = new ChatListFragment();
        Utils.openFragment(this, chatFragment, false, tasksTitle + "Fragment");
    }
```

openFragment() method

```
public static void openFragment(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity, Fragment fragment, boolean addTobackStack, String tag) {
    try {

        FragmentManager fm = appCompatActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        String fragmentName = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
        fm.popBackStack(fragmentName, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = appCompatActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (addTobackStack) {
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentName);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I believe it's related to finding the id of recyclerview, just can't figure out the correct way to do so.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code of `openChatFragment()`

Comment: @Zain , I have updated the code

Comment: The call has only one parameter which is `null`, and the method signature has more than one parameter

Comment: Please check I have added 2 method , `openChatFragment` which uses `openFragment` , I have provided code for both methods

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing the UI that is in fragment, then you can you inbuilt methods of fragment testing of espresso.

Dependency for fragment testing with espresso

```
dependencies {
    def fragment_version = "1.3.6"

    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragment_version"
}
```

To launch fragment, write following code in your setup method

```kotlin
val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<EventFragment>(fragmentArgs)
```

You can get more info regarding fragment testing in espresso [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/test)

Comment: Does this required kotlin support , as I cannot find any java documentation

Comment: Yes it will work with java also. But you need to check syntax for that. You can check here the method i mentioned "launchFragmentInContainer" in java. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/testing/FragmentScenario.Companion

Answer (score 0):

Use the Barista library for UI tests, it is the easiest solution and makes everything easier. https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista

Inside it, try to use RecyclerView testing methods:

```
clickListItem(R.id.list, 4);
clickListItemChild(R.id.list, 3, R.id.row_button);
scrollListToPosition(R.id.list, 4);

assertDisplayedAtPosition(R.id.list, 0, "text");
assertDisplayedAtPosition(R.id.list, 0, R.id.text_field, "text");
assertDisplayedAtPosition(R.id.list, 0, R.string.hello_world);
assertDisplayedAtPosition(R.id.list, 0, R.id.text_field, 
R.string.hello_world);
assertDrawableDisplayedAtPosition(R.id.recycler, 0, R.id.imageview, 
R.drawable.ic_barista);
```

Comment: Isn't there any solution without the use of third party library

Comment: You can check library methods and how are they doing it, and use parts of code that you need and work for you.

Comment: Good idea , let me check code and see if that's work